# LINQ to SQL designer not opening/timing out (VS 2022)

Tags: linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2022, windows-11

On Visual Studio 2022, Windows 11.

**Linq to SQL tools** is installed from installer (Individual Components).

When right clicking a dbml file and *View Designer*, it just sticks on this and eventually needs an end task:

[image: DBML fail]

Tried (to no avail):

- Clearing all app.config connection strings in the same project (in case it was silently barfing on one of those)
- Installing older .NET frameworks, ticking on *Data Storage and Processing* and *Data sources and service references*

Any ideas what might be causing this? (Ran OK under Win 10 / VS 2022).

**Edit:** I've had this after every new PC install with Win 11, VS 2022 (3 work PCs), but it seems to resolve itself after a few days. I now know why, see marked answer re toolbox.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Viewing the Toolbox and (optionally) resetting it (right click > Reset) seems to solve this. It seems the designer can't open when the toolbox is not initialised (or fails to initialise). It is often a while before I open the toolbox on a new install so I kept on encountering this problem.

Comment: wow i am amazed this worked, thank you, i wonder how did you discovered this, and why Microsoft is not doing anything about it

Comment: @CristianOlaru just a pure chance discovery, was a very annoying undocumented issue.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW this Toolbox thing didn't work for me. The fix for me (using VS 2019) was the following:

1. Type "Linq to SQL" in the Visual Studio search box (in the top nav/toolbar)
2. Clicking the resulting "Install Linq to SQL Tools" link
3. Letting the install finish/reloading Visual Studio

[Source](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/linq-to-sql-dbml-designer-in-not-working/4616)

Comment: Different issue not having it installed.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem on Win8 with VS 2015 and 2017 and 2019, Win10 with VS 2015 and 2017. I did not solve the problem. Do not know what causes this problem. But now on Win11 with 2022 I opened my problematic DBML file, it took really long time to open (during opening it showed Not responding etc.) but finally VS opened DBML file. Then I made a change in the designer (just moved class a little bit = change = auto-generated file will be re-generated after save) and saved. Now this particular DBML file is opened within a second. Try it.